# checking the internet connection

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping, ping, internet-connection

I am checking the internet connection at "Form_Load" event but as per the experiences from the users that installed my application ( windows desktop - std package to cd installation ) that it is not giving an error at the first run

The tool immediately start webscraping after checking of the internet connection

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    Try

        If My.Computer.Network.Ping("www.google.com") Then


        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        '' Else ''

        Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Tekrar denemek ister misiniz ?", "Internet bağlantınız yok", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        If result = vbRetry Then
            Application.Restart()
        Else
            Close()
        End If
    End Try
```

My question is about, how to create much more convenient method for internet connection checking during all the time especially at the first loading of the program

Comment: You didn't set a TimeOut for that Ping (500 ms as default). In `Form.Load`, it could Timeout on its own without any exception. You could use the overload that allows you to specify a Timeout. OR, couple the polling with the [Network.NetworkAvailabilityChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.network.networkavailabilitychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) (this one is specific for VB.Net). Read the notes there. There are much more complex ways to handle this, using the Windows installer specific APIs.

Comment: @Jimi, please correct me if i am wrong but the computer can connect to network but not to internet, right? Is it good to track network then? Sorry for the beginner level question

Comment: I didn't say that. A NetworkAvailabilityChange is notified whenever something changes in relation to general network availability. This just signals the event. When you receive the signal, you may want to verify whether the change is related to your specific context. This allows to avoid polling the SNMP interface. About the Ping itself, I'ld suggest to move it to the `Shown()` event of the `Form`. Or even later, setting a timer in the Shown() event that, when elapsed, will call `Ping()` and then is Disposed.  Any further checks can be performed just when a network change is notified.

Comment: To note, however, that a Ping() check is not that much reliable. Its success may depends on the local network setup and Firewalls/Routers/DNS/hosts configuration. Also, you might want to Ping `8.8.8.8` instead of a `www` host. You may never know where you end up pinging that in some networks.

Comment: @jimi Thank you so much